# Python: How to convert a full date stamp into just a date stamp

Tags: python, date, python-2.6

I am very new to python (2.6.7)
How would I be able convert the output of:

```
todays_date = datetime.datetime.today()  
print todays_date
yesterday = todays_date - timedelta(days=1)
print yesterday
```

Which yields to:

```
2015-11-22 23:44:45.166081
2015-11-21 23:44:45.166081
```

From this, I want to change the format of `yesterday` to just `21/11/2015`
How could this be done?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `datetime` object then to get a date part, call its [`.date()` method](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.date):

```
just_date = some_datetime.date()
```

Note: don't confuse a `date` object such `date.today()` and its text representation such as `str(date.today())`:

```
>>> from datetime import date, timedelta
>>> yesterday = date.today() - timedelta(1) 
>>> yesterday
datetime.date(2015, 11, 22)
>>> str(yesterday)
'2015-11-22'
>>> print yesterday
2015-11-22
>>> yesterday.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
'22/11/2015'
```